# Convert Html to markdown using xwiki

Tags: java, markdown, xwiki

How do i convert from html to markdown with xwiki,

Getting "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fRecognizedFeatures" for shouldRenderHtmlToMarkdown, tried different formats of html.

```
public class HtmlRendererTest
{
    private Converter converter;
    private WikiPrinter printer;

    @Test
    public void testHtmlToMarkdown() throws ComponentLookupException, ConversionException, ParseException, ComponentRepositoryException
    {
        WikiPrinter printer = new DefaultWikiPrinter();
        converter.convert(new StringReader("<h3 id=\"HHeader3\"><span>Header 3</span></h3>"), Syntax.XHTML_1_0, Syntax.MARKDOWN_1_1,  printer);

        System.out.println(printer.toString());
        assertThat(printer.toString(), containsString("###"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMarkdownToHtml() throws ComponentLookupException, ConversionException, ParseException, ComponentRepositoryException
    {
        WikiPrinter printer = new DefaultWikiPrinter();
        converter.convert(new StringReader("### Header 3"), Syntax.MARKDOWN_1_1, Syntax.ANNOTATED_XHTML_1_0, printer);

        System.out.println(printer.toString());
        assertThat(printer.toString(), containsString("</h3>"));
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ComponentLookupException, ConversionException
    {
        EmbeddableComponentManager componentManager = new EmbeddableComponentManager();
        componentManager.initialize(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

        converter = componentManager.getInstance(Converter.class);
        printer = new DefaultWikiPrinter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

XWiki only provide a parser for Markdown right now so unless you wrote a markdown serializer yourself shouldRenderHtmlToMarkdown cannot really work.

Now it's not what "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fRecognizedFeatures" is about, usually it means you have some incompatible jars (one class expect to find a field but the target class is not in the expected version). The complete stack trace might help understanding which ones.